# Retrieve user by Sanctum plainTextToken

Tags: laravel, laravel-sanctum

How to retrieve the 'logged in' user from a Sanctum token.

For logging in I have the following method

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt($request->toArray())) {

        /* @var User $user */
        $user = $request->user();

        $token = $user->createToken('web-token')->plainTextToken;

        return response()->json([
            'user' => $user,
            'token' => $token,
        ], Response::HTTP_OK);
    }
}
```

Now for logging out I use a custom method.

```
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    dd($request->user()); // <- Always returns null
}
```

I want to revoke the token, but I don't know how to retrieve the currently logged in user. Obviously for logging out I send the Authorization header with the Bearer and plainTextToken as value.

Comment: Did you try `Auth::user()`?

Comment: @Makdous Yeah that returns null. Because there is no logged in user via session.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

for sure you have first add token in bearer token

and to get user out of sanctum middleware now token is optional

```
$user = auth('sanctum')->user();
```

than log out

```
if ($user) {
    $user->currentAccessToken()->delete();
}
```

note : this delete only current token

if u need all tokens use

```
foreach ($user->tokens as $token) {
     $token->delete();
}
```

Comment: where is that certain token saved?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't use the default Sanctum middleware, you can get the user from the plain text token as follow:

```php
use \Laravel\Sanctum\PersonalAccessToken;

/** @var PersonalAccessToken personalAccessToken */
$personalAccessToken = PersonalAccessToken::findToken($plainTextToken);

/** @var mixed $user */
$user = $personalAccessToken->tokenable;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're sending the bearer/token to the *Logout url* you can try to override the `logout` function of the `AuthenticatesUsers`:

```
    /**
* Log the user out of the application.
*
* @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
* @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
*/
public function logout(Request $request)
{
    $this->guard()->logout();

    $request->user()->tokens()->delete();

    return redirect('/');
}
```

Comment: Sorry to clarify myself, I am not using the default logout url, but a custom one. Also if I dd $request->user() it returns null since there is no active user.

Answer (score 0):

simply add the route within middleware('auth:sanctum') grouped routes
then from inside the targeted function you can get user like this auth()->user()
or if you just want to log out the user you can revoke token like this
$request->user()->currentAccessToken()->delete();